# AVerMedia Broadcaster HD not working in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-8, pci-express, video-capture, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a machine running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard equipped with an AVerMedia Broadcaster HD, when using the RECentral program it says the device is occupied and to close the conflicting program. From what I have found no program or process should be accessing the device. Is there a feature of the OS causing this error, or some setting I have overlooked?

Further: I recently did an SSD upgrade in my main PC and booting off my old SSD with Win 8.1 Pro in the server the capture card and program works fine allowing me to view the captured video.

Thanks in advance, I have looked everywhere and this is frustrating me to no end now.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked their website.

Assuming this is your product: [Here](http://www.avermedia-usa.com/avertv/Product/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=503)

It clearly shows that:

[image]

This card is not compatible with Windows Server 2012. Only 8/7/Vista